# Регулярное выражение: у русских слов нет границы "\b"?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает граница слова `\b` для русских слов, в то время, когда для английских работает.

```js
var str = "one один two два three"

var work = str.match(/([\w])+\b|([а-я])+/giu);
console.log(work, ":Без \\b для русских слов:");

                                      //вот тут
var notWork = str.match(/([\w])+\b|([а-я])+\b/giu);
console.log( notWork, ":c \\b для русских слов:");
```

Comment: Они там не знаю, что есть буквы отличные от латиницы.

Comment: Именно так, "словом" считает то где есть латиница в любом кейсе, цифры, знак подчеркивания. Подробнее в спеке примерно здесь https://bterlson.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-wordcharacters-abstract-operation

Comment: @Дмытрык модификатор `u` вам в помощь.

Comment: @Эдуард, флаг `u` не помогает. Обновил вопрос и добавил его в код.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Правила работы регулярных выражений описаны в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-assertion)

При проверке `\b` выполняются следующие шаги:

1. Выполняется функция `IsWordChar` для текущего символа и предыдущего.
2. Если полученные значения различаются - возвращается `true`
3. В противном случае - `false`.

Что представляет из себя функция [`IsWordChar`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-iswordchar-abstract-operation)?

В данной функции идет простая проверка вхождения символа в заранее заданный список символов. Список символов включает в себя следующие 63 (26*2+10+1) символов, жестко прописанных в спецификации:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   _
```

Как видно, здесь отсутствуют все символы, кроме английского, цифр и знака подчеркивания.

Comment: Спасибо, исчерпывающий ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Для себя нашел решение для обозначения границы слова следующим образом:

```
(?<=\s|^)Слово(?=\s|$)
```