# Поиск и замена в javasript -replace

Tags: javascript, replace

**Такая задача:**
В поле textarea вставляется копируемый текст. В этом тексте надо найти и заменить определенные слова.
Кроме этого надо записать количество измененных слов. У меня получилось так. Но мне кажется что есть ещё более короткий путь. К примеру чтобы count один раз написать или слова функцию replace тоже использовать один раз в цикле. Но не знаю как.
Спасибо за каждую помощь

```js
﻿function Ivazkuni(){

    var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var count = 0;

    // Первый поиск и замена
    var imlo = str
    .replace(/руз/g,function(){ count = count+1; return 'рӯз'; })
    .replace(/куҳ/g,function(){ count = count+1; return 'кӯҳ'; })
    .replace(/Руз/g,"Рӯз")
    .replace(/кӯҳна/g,"куҳна")
    .replace(/дуст/g,"дӯст")
    .replace(/Дуст/g,"Дӯст")
    .replace(/У/g,"Ӯ")
    .replace(/вҷ/g,"ҷв");
    document.getElementById("text").value = imlo;
    console.log(count);


}
```

```html
<textarea name="name" id="text" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
<button onclick="Ivazkuni()">Try it</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="replace.js"></script>
```

Comment: это что то типо переводчика?

Comment: ну типа проверка правописание слов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так, если я правильно понял задачу:

```js
const replacements = new Map([
  [/руз/g, 'рӯз'],
  [/куҳ/g, 'кӯҳ'],
  [/Руз/g, 'Рӯз'],
  [/кӯҳна/g, 'куҳна'],
  [/дуст/g, 'дӯст'],
  [/Дуст/g, 'Дӯст'],
  [/У/g, 'Ӯ'],
  [/вҷ/g, 'ҷв'],
]);

function Ivazkuni(){
    let str = document.getElementById("text").value;
    let count = 0;

    for (const [regexp, replacement] of replacements) {
      str = str.replace(regexp, () => { count++; return replacement });
    }

    document.getElementById("text").value = str;
    console.log(count);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="name" id="text" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
<button onclick="Ivazkuni()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Что означает `new Map` в данном контексте и почему нельзя было обойтись без него?

Comment: Map в данном контексте выбрано потому, что ключами там могут выступать не только строки: так нам удобно будет хранить пары из ключа-регулярного выражения и значения-подстановки, чтобы обходить их в цикле.

Comment: При добавление регулярного выраж типа : [/^У$)/g, 'Ӯ'] выдает ошибку. Почему?

Comment: У вас есть закрывающая круглая скобка, но нет открывающей.

Comment: Ещё раз большое спасибо вам

Comment: И вам удачи в работе)

Comment: А как решить проблему кодировки русских слов в границах слов типа: /\bслово\b/gu

Comment: Ппоскольку `\b` работает только с базовой латиницей, можно использовать [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes): `/(?<!\p{L})[А-ЯЁа-яё]+(?!\p{L})/` или более универсально `/(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?!\p{L})/`

Comment: а как найти к примеру слово "школа" через этот рег-выражение : /(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?!\p{L})/

Comment: `/(?<!\p{L})школа(?!\p{L})/` — найдёт слово "школа", не окружённое буквами любого алфавита.

Comment: /(?<!\p{L})СПАСИБО!(?!\p{L})/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись одним регулярным выражением используя [символ `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#types) указывающий альтернативы поиска.

В этом случае замена и подсчет будут происходит в одном вызове `.replace`.

```js
function Ivazkuni() {

  var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var count = 0;

  var map = {
    'руз': 'рӯз',
    'куҳ': 'кӯҳ',
    'Руз': 'Рӯз',
    'кӯҳна': 'куҳна',
    'дуст': 'дӯст',
    'Дуст': 'Дӯст',
    'У': 'Ӯ',
    'вҷ': 'ҷв'
  };

  // Первый поиск и замена
  var imlo = str.replace(/руз|куҳ|Руз|кӯҳна|дуст|Дуст|У|вҷ/g, function($) {
    count += 1;
    return map[$];
  });
  document.getElementById("text").value = imlo;
  console.log(count);


}
```

```html
<textarea name="name" id="text" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
<button onclick="Ivazkuni()">Try it</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="replace.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как решить проблему кодировки русских слов в границах слов типа: /\bслово\b/gu –

Comment: @Нуримаърифат, [Регулярное выражение: у русских слов нет границы “\b”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770924/186999)

Comment: а как решить проблему тогда?

Comment: @Нуримаърифат, заменить `\b` на другое выражение, учитывающее и русские буквы.

Comment: не могу найти выражения для поиска целостного слова на русском.

Comment: @Нуримаърифат, оно и не нужно, просто вместо `\b` используй проверку что это не русские буквы