# Как красить заданные слова без запятых и точек?

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, строки, dom

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

let str = document.querySelectorAll('p');
let arrStr = Array.from(str);

function findWords(lorem) {
  lorem = lorem.forEach((element, index) => {
    element = element.innerText.split(' ');
    for (let j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        // if (element[i].includes(',') || element[i].includes('.')) {
        //     // console.log(element.splice(i, 1, colors[j], element[i].slice(-1)))
        //     // element.splice(i, 1)        
        //     // element[i].innerText.split(','); 
        // //   element[i].innerText.join('') 
        // }   
        // console.log(element[i])
        if (element[i].replace(',', '').replace('.', '') === colors[j]) {
          console.log(`Найдено:  ${element[i]}`)
          element[i] = `<span style="color: ${colors[j]}">${element[i]}</span>`;
        }

      }
    }
    lorem[index].innerHTML = element.join(' ')
    console.log(element)
  });
}
console.log(findWords(arrStr))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet lacinia libero. Aliquam vehicula sapien eget nunc tempus, id faucibus lorem red pellentesque. Etiam sodales elit ante, sed rhoncus tortor faucibus vel. Vestibulum nec arcu neque.
    Maecenas dui sem, efficitur quis elit non, lacinia blue placerat risus. Sed mattis est purus. Pellentesque blandit eros ligula, yellow ac fermentum green magna interdum red maximus. Phasellus erat urna, dictum eu porta quis, ornare quis ligula.</p>
  <p>Maecenas consequat, leo in tempus blandit, massa ligula faucibus dolor, at feugiat odio elit sed elit. Quisque molestie nulla in orci facilisis, et auctor mauris elementum. Sed mi neque, efficitur ut aliquet a, luctus lobortis lectus. Nunc pretium cursus
    nisi, at aliquet erat viverra sed. Phasellus red erat ligula, maximus quis tincidunt eget, porttitor at dui. Mauris ut urna pharetra, mollis lacus at, posuere nisl. Aliquam a dapibus mi. Pellentesque vestibulum porta erat at maximus. Duis posuere
    tincidunt purus, vitae volutpat lectus varius vitae. Nam rutrum blue venenatis augue vel commodo. Suspendisse nec nulla eros.</p>
  <p>Duis lorem est bluetoth, blandit eget leo pharetra, rutrum semper ante. Suspendisse vestibulum in risus id hendrerit. Nulla volutpat velit ac tortor lacinia euismod. In non purus dictum, pellentesque mauris ac, viverra est. Phasellus urna odio, sodales
    et nisl sed, condimentum volutpat ex. Duis et vulputate urna. Praesent sollicitudin lacinia felis, nec facilisis purus venenatis in. Integer yellow et lacus green dapibus eros vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque ultricies, nunc yellow dictum yellow luctus blue posuere, orci ex dapibus tortor, vel ultrices nulla velit quis neque. Mauris nisl ligula, lobortis id metus quis, gravida eleifend diam. Curabitur sapien nibh, faucibus sed diam et, luctus
    imperdiet risus. Cras urna nunc, luctus sit amet red libero ac, tristique egestas nibh. Cras dui elit, malesuada sit amet quam eget, efficitur maximus magna. Nulla auctor dignissim dictum. Curabitur condimentum semper lacus, tristique bibendum justo
    lobortis et. Interdum green et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus finibus diam at auctor condimentum. Morbi at nisi nec purus red maximus pulvinar. Duis at lorem ultricies, blandit velit sed, condimentum justo. Suspendisse
    potenti.</p>
  <p>Redux, Morbi accumsan tortor eros, vel consectetur lectus iaculis red vitae. Integer rhoncus imperdiet purus, in mattis justo tempor at. Sed tristique porta ligula, eu gravida erat red congue ac. Donec leo justo, fermentum nec nisi auctor, vulputate
    fringilla ex. Morbi ut tempor tortor, quis tincidunt velit. Integer in commodo lorem. Sed vestibulum vestibulum mi at semper. Suspendisse nisi tellus, vestibulum porttitor purus nec, pharetra semper erat. Sed lorem blue turpis, euismod sit amet hendrerit
    non, red, yellow. consequat ac tellus. Fusce nec iaculis elit. Cras non molestie est. Aenean faucibus neque metus, nec tempus est consequat et. Quisque accumsan, turpis vel vulputate dignissim, dui erat scelerisque enim, sit amet auctor nisl green
    arcu non odio. Quisque eleifend id dolor a egestas.</p>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без регулярок. Алгоритм:

1. Создаём массив цветов
2. Массив допустимых символов, которые могут быть после цвета

   2.1 Создаём набор ([new Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) допустимых символов. **Наборы позволяют не тратить время на поиск, но занимают место в памяти**
3. Создаём набор всевозможных комбинаций цветов и допустимых символов
4. Находим все параграфы
5. В каждом параграфе разбиваем содержимое по пробелам и получаем массив
6. Создаём новый массив, куда записываем видоизменённые элементы разбиения
7. Сначала проверяем есть ли в наборе всевозможных комбинаций цветов и допустимых символов очередное слово из разбиенния
8. Если нет, то просто не трогаем это слово. Если есть, разделяем слово на 2 переменные
9. В одной переменной слово без последнего символа, в другой последний символ
10. Смотрим, если последний символ это один из допустимых символов, значит цвет - это слово без последнего символа, если это не так, значит само слово и есть цвет
11. Заменяем слово на то что нам нужно и дальше объединяя все слова по пробелам встаялем в параграф обратно

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
const availableSymbols = ['.', ',', '!', '?'];
const availableSymbolsSet = new Set(availableSymbols);

const colorsWithSymbols = new Set(colors);

colors.forEach(color => {
  availableSymbols.forEach(availableSymbol => {
    colorsWithSymbols.add(color + availableSymbol);
  })
});

const colorizeWord = (color, lastSymbol = '') => `<span style="color: ${color}">${color}</span>${lastSymbol}`;

const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
  const words = paragraph.innerHTML.split(' ');
  
  const formattedWords = words.map(word => {
    if (!colorsWithSymbols.has(word)) return word;
    
    const lastSymbol = word[word.length - 1];
    const wordWithoutLastSymbol = word.slice(0, -1);
    
    return availableSymbolsSet.has(lastSymbol) ? colorizeWord(wordWithoutLastSymbol, lastSymbol) : colorizeWord(word);

  });
  
  paragraph.innerHTML = formattedWords.join(' ');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet lacinia libero. Aliquam vehicula sapien eget nunc tempus, id faucibus lorem red pellentesque. Etiam sodales elit ante, sed rhoncus tortor faucibus vel. Vestibulum nec arcu neque. Maecenas
  dui sem, efficitur quis elit non, lacinia blue placerat risus. Sed mattis est purus. Pellentesque blandit eros ligula, yellow ac fermentum green magna interdum red maximus. Phasellus erat urna, dictum eu porta quis, ornare quis ligula.</p>
<p>Maecenas consequat, leo in tempus blandit, massa ligula faucibus dolor, at feugiat odio elit sed elit. Quisque molestie nulla in orci facilisis, et auctor mauris elementum. Sed mi neque, efficitur ut aliquet a, luctus lobortis lectus. Nunc pretium cursus
  nisi, at aliquet erat viverra sed. Phasellus red erat ligula, maximus quis tincidunt eget, porttitor at dui. Mauris ut urna pharetra, mollis lacus at, posuere nisl. Aliquam a dapibus mi. Pellentesque vestibulum porta erat at maximus. Duis posuere tincidunt
  purus, vitae volutpat lectus varius vitae. Nam rutrum blue venenatis augue vel commodo. Suspendisse nec nulla eros.</p>
<p>Duis lorem est bluetoth, blandit eget leo pharetra, rutrum semper ante. Suspendisse vestibulum in risus id hendrerit. Nulla volutpat velit ac tortor lacinia euismod. In non purus dictum, pellentesque mauris ac, viverra est. Phasellus urna odio, sodales
  et nisl sed, condimentum volutpat ex. Duis et vulputate urna. Praesent sollicitudin lacinia felis, nec facilisis purus venenatis in. Integer yellow et lacus green dapibus eros vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
<p>Pellentesque ultricies, nunc yellow dictum yellow luctus blue posuere, orci ex dapibus tortor, vel ultrices nulla velit quis neque. Mauris nisl ligula, lobortis id metus quis, gravida eleifend diam. Curabitur sapien nibh, faucibus sed diam et, luctus
  imperdiet risus. Cras urna nunc, luctus sit amet red libero ac, tristique egestas nibh. Cras dui elit, malesuada sit amet quam eget, efficitur maximus magna. Nulla auctor dignissim dictum. Curabitur condimentum semper lacus, tristique bibendum justo
  lobortis et. Interdum green et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus finibus diam at auctor condimentum. Morbi at nisi nec purus red maximus pulvinar. Duis at lorem ultricies, blandit velit sed, condimentum justo. Suspendisse potenti.
</p>
<p>Redux, Morbi accumsan tortor eros, vel consectetur lectus iaculis red vitae. Integer rhoncus imperdiet purus, in mattis justo tempor at. Sed tristique porta ligula, eu gravida erat red congue ac. Donec leo justo, fermentum nec nisi auctor, vulputate fringilla
  ex. Morbi ut tempor tortor, quis tincidunt velit. Integer in commodo lorem. Sed vestibulum vestibulum mi at semper. Suspendisse nisi tellus, vestibulum porttitor purus nec, pharetra semper erat. Sed lorem blue turpis, euismod sit amet hendrerit non,
  red, yellow. consequat ac tellus. Fusce nec iaculis elit. Cras non molestie est. Aenean faucibus neque metus, nec tempus est consequat et. Quisque accumsan, turpis vel vulputate dignissim, dui erat scelerisque enim, sit amet auctor nisl green arcu non
  odio. Quisque eleifend id dolor a egestas.</p>
```

Вариант с регулярками. Алгоритм:

1. Создаём регулярку с помощью [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

   1.1 Добавил по краям `\b` чтобы захватывать только данные слова польностью. Т.е. чтобы они не были частью других слов. Чтобы добавить `\b` надо писать `\\b` для экранизации `\`. Если вам надо подкрашивать данные слова так же внутри других слов, то вам надо убрать `\\b(` и `)\\b`

   1.2 Не добавил флаг `i`, т.к. не знал нужно ли вам учитывать регистр или нет

   1.3 Флаг `g` нужен как для глобального поиска так и обязателен для использования `replaceAll`
2. Проходимся по всем тегам `p` и меняем их содержимое с помощью [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
const regexp = new RegExp(`\\b(${colors.join('|')})\\b`, 'g');

console.log(regexp);

const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replaceAll(regexp, '<span style="color: $&;">$&</span>'));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet lacinia libero. Aliquam vehicula sapien eget nunc tempus, id faucibus lorem red pellentesque. Etiam sodales elit ante, sed rhoncus tortor faucibus vel. Vestibulum nec arcu neque. Maecenas
  dui sem, efficitur quis elit non, lacinia blue placerat risus. Sed mattis est purus. Pellentesque blandit eros ligula, yellow ac fermentum green magna interdum red maximus. Phasellus erat urna, dictum eu porta quis, ornare quis ligula.</p>
<p>Maecenas consequat, leo in tempus blandit, massa ligula faucibus dolor, at feugiat odio elit sed elit. Quisque molestie nulla in orci facilisis, et auctor mauris elementum. Sed mi neque, efficitur ut aliquet a, luctus lobortis lectus. Nunc pretium cursus
  nisi, at aliquet erat viverra sed. Phasellus red erat ligula, maximus quis tincidunt eget, porttitor at dui. Mauris ut urna pharetra, mollis lacus at, posuere nisl. Aliquam a dapibus mi. Pellentesque vestibulum porta erat at maximus. Duis posuere tincidunt
  purus, vitae volutpat lectus varius vitae. Nam rutrum blue venenatis augue vel commodo. Suspendisse nec nulla eros.</p>
<p>Duis lorem est bluetoth, blandit eget leo pharetra, rutrum semper ante. Suspendisse vestibulum in risus id hendrerit. Nulla volutpat velit ac tortor lacinia euismod. In non purus dictum, pellentesque mauris ac, viverra est. Phasellus urna odio, sodales
  et nisl sed, condimentum volutpat ex. Duis et vulputate urna. Praesent sollicitudin lacinia felis, nec facilisis purus venenatis in. Integer yellow et lacus green dapibus eros vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
<p>Pellentesque ultricies, nunc yellow dictum yellow luctus blue posuere, orci ex dapibus tortor, vel ultrices nulla velit quis neque. Mauris nisl ligula, lobortis id metus quis, gravida eleifend diam. Curabitur sapien nibh, faucibus sed diam et, luctus
  imperdiet risus. Cras urna nunc, luctus sit amet red libero ac, tristique egestas nibh. Cras dui elit, malesuada sit amet quam eget, efficitur maximus magna. Nulla auctor dignissim dictum. Curabitur condimentum semper lacus, tristique bibendum justo
  lobortis et. Interdum green et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus finibus diam at auctor condimentum. Morbi at nisi nec purus red maximus pulvinar. Duis at lorem ultricies, blandit velit sed, condimentum justo. Suspendisse potenti.
</p>
<p>Redux, Morbi accumsan tortor eros, vel consectetur lectus iaculis red vitae. Integer rhoncus imperdiet purus, in mattis justo tempor at. Sed tristique porta ligula, eu gravida erat red congue ac. Donec leo justo, fermentum nec nisi auctor, vulputate fringilla
  ex. Morbi ut tempor tortor, quis tincidunt velit. Integer in commodo lorem. Sed vestibulum vestibulum mi at semper. Suspendisse nisi tellus, vestibulum porttitor purus nec, pharetra semper erat. Sed lorem blue turpis, euismod sit amet hendrerit non,
  red, yellow. consequat ac tellus. Fusce nec iaculis elit. Cras non molestie est. Aenean faucibus neque metus, nec tempus est consequat et. Quisque accumsan, turpis vel vulputate dignissim, dui erat scelerisque enim, sit amet auctor nisl green arcu non
  odio. Quisque eleifend id dolor a egestas.</p>
```

Comment: Вроде бы можно использовать обыкновенный `replace`, если указан флаг `g`.

Comment: А есть способы без регулярок и без replaceAll?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Можно, но по смыслу мне больше наравится этот метод :)

Comment: @minorio А что вместо `replaceAll` вы хотите чтобы я использовал?

Comment: Дело в том, что я в регулярках не особо смыслю и само моё задание предполагает решение без этих штук. Видимо надо было добавить комментарий, а то вела всех в заблуждение :(

Comment: @EzioMercer просто потом в коде будет удобно переключатся на изменение только одной совпавшей строки вместо всех, ну если вам конечно больше он нравится, то тогда используй дальше `replaceAll`.

Comment: Я рассчитывала на то, что люди начнут развивать мой закоменченный код ( если это вообще возможно), а не создавать новый. Возможно это сделать через if?
P.S В любом случае, я понимаю что это ошибка корректности моего вопроса, надо было уточнить)

Comment: @minorio Так вы используете `replace`, почему нельзя `replaceAll`?

Comment: Это предполагает задание, реплейсОлл не использовать

Comment: @minorio Но в целом я вас понял, щас придумаю :)

Comment: @minorio Готово, пользуйтесь :)

Comment: Премного благодарна ^_^

Comment: `\b` работает только с английскими буквами

Comment: @Grundy Да? Интересно, а что используют для мультиязычного варианта?

Comment: @EzioMercer [Регулярное выражение: у русских слов нет границы "\b"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770924/186999) - все зависит от того, что конкретно ты считаешь словом

Comment: @Grundy Пусть словом будет последовательность любой длины из букв из любого алфавита. Например как работает `/\p{L}+/u`. Но если в регулярке я напишу это, то он абсолютно каждое слово обернёт в спан. Можно, конечно создать набор данных слов и каждый раз проверять найденное слово есть в наборе или нет. А можно эту задачу решить чисто регуляркой? Да, бразуер не будет воспринимать `color: красный`, но чисто гипотетически если можно было бы интересно как бы ты это сделал

Comment: @EzioMercer, не понял комментарий. Если у тебя есть конкретные слова для выделения - все что тебе нужно, проверить что вокруг них стоит по символу не из разрешенных

Comment: @Grundy Так их тоже дофига, не могу же я их всех по одному перечислять. Ну представь большой набор, где с каждого существующего языка взято к примеру по 5 слов, что тогда делать?

Comment: @EzioMercer у тебя же есть `\p{L}`. По ссылке выше есть пример с пробелами

Comment: @Grundy А как его использовать? Всё что приходит в голову это использовать `/(?<=[^\p{L}])(красный|red)(?=[^\p{L}])/gu`, но `(?<=)` работает не везде

Comment: @EzioMercer, да, этот вариант и имел ввиду. Когда его нигде не было, тоже был вариант, можешь попробовать поискать в вопросах

Answer (score 1):

Предложу вот такой вариант раскраски...

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
let re = '(?<=[^\\w])(' + colors.join('|') + ')(?=[^\\w])'
re = new RegExp(re, 'gi')
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(o => {
  o.innerHTML = o.innerHTML.replace(re, '<span style="color: $&;">$&</span>')
})
```

```html
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet lacinia libero. Aliquam vehicula sapien eget nunc tempus, id faucibus lorem red pellentesque. Etiam sodales elit ante, sed rhoncus tortor faucibus vel. Vestibulum nec arcu neque.
    Maecenas dui sem, efficitur quis elit non, lacinia blue placerat risus. Sed mattis est purus. Pellentesque blandit eros ligula, yellow ac fermentum green magna interdum red maximus. Phasellus erat urna, dictum eu porta quis, ornare quis ligula.</p>
  <p>Maecenas consequat, leo in tempus blandit, massa ligula faucibus dolor, at feugiat odio elit sed elit. Quisque molestie nulla in orci facilisis, et auctor mauris elementum. Sed mi neque, efficitur ut aliquet a, luctus lobortis lectus. Nunc pretium cursus
    nisi, at aliquet erat viverra sed. Phasellus red erat ligula, maximus quis tincidunt eget, porttitor at dui. Mauris ut urna pharetra, mollis lacus at, posuere nisl. Aliquam a dapibus mi. Pellentesque vestibulum porta erat at maximus. Duis posuere
    tincidunt purus, vitae volutpat lectus varius vitae. Nam rutrum blue venenatis augue vel commodo. Suspendisse nec nulla eros.</p>
  <p>Duis lorem est bluetoth, blandit eget leo pharetra, rutrum semper ante. Suspendisse vestibulum in risus id hendrerit. Nulla volutpat velit ac tortor lacinia euismod. In non purus dictum, pellentesque mauris ac, viverra est. Phasellus urna odio, sodales
    et nisl sed, condimentum volutpat ex. Duis et vulputate urna. Praesent sollicitudin lacinia felis, nec facilisis purus venenatis in. Integer yellow et lacus green dapibus eros vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque ultricies, nunc yellow dictum yellow luctus blue posuere, orci ex dapibus tortor, vel ultrices nulla velit quis neque. Mauris nisl ligula, lobortis id metus quis, gravida eleifend diam. Curabitur sapien nibh, faucibus sed diam et, luctus
    imperdiet risus. Cras urna nunc, luctus sit amet red libero ac, tristique egestas nibh. Cras dui elit, malesuada sit amet quam eget, efficitur maximus magna. Nulla auctor dignissim dictum. Curabitur condimentum semper lacus, tristique bibendum justo
    lobortis et. Interdum green et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus finibus diam at auctor condimentum. Morbi at nisi nec purus red maximus pulvinar. Duis at lorem ultricies, blandit velit sed, condimentum justo. Suspendisse
    potenti.</p>
  <p>Redux, Morbi accumsan tortor eros, vel consectetur lectus iaculis red vitae. Integer rhoncus imperdiet purus, in mattis justo tempor at. Sed tristique porta ligula, eu gravida erat red congue ac. Donec leo justo, fermentum nec nisi auctor, vulputate
    fringilla ex. Morbi ut tempor tortor, quis tincidunt velit. Integer in commodo lorem. Sed vestibulum vestibulum mi at semper. Suspendisse nisi tellus, vestibulum porttitor purus nec, pharetra semper erat. Sed lorem blue turpis, euismod sit amet hendrerit
    non, red, yellow. consequat ac tellus. Fusce nec iaculis elit. Cras non molestie est. Aenean faucibus neque metus, nec tempus est consequat et. Quisque accumsan, turpis vel vulputate dignissim, dui erat scelerisque enim, sit amet auctor nisl green
    arcu non odio. Quisque eleifend id dolor a egestas.</p>
```

Comment: Правда пока не пойму почему подкрашивается "bluetoth" в третьем абзаце... Хотя такая регулярка /(?<=[^\w])blue(?=[^\w])/gi не подкрашивает...

Comment: "Redux" ведь не подкрашивается в пятом абзаце... Чем "особенный" этот blue - пока не понятно. :(

Comment: экранируйте слеши в переменной re.

Comment: Да, это решило проблему.

Answer (score -1):

Вот решение :)

```js
let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']

class ChangeColor {
  constructor(els) {
    if(els) {
      if(els instanceof NodeList) {
        this.els = Array.from(els)
      } else if(els instanceof HTMLElement) {
        this.els = [els]
      } else {
        this.els = []
      }
    } else {
      this.els = []
    }
  }

  addElement(el) {
    if(el instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.els.push(el)
      return true
    }

    return false
  }

  init(colors) {
    let els = this.els

    for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
      let el = els[i]

      for (let j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
        let color = colors[j]
        let resultHTML = el.innerHTML.replaceAll(color, `<span style="color: ${color};">${color}</span>`)

        el.innerHTML = resultHTML
      }
    }
  }
}

let parags = document.querySelectorAll('p')

new ChangeColor(parags)
  .init(colors)
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet lacinia libero. Aliquam vehicula sapien eget nunc tempus, id faucibus lorem red pellentesque. Etiam sodales elit ante, sed rhoncus tortor faucibus vel. Vestibulum nec arcu neque.
    Maecenas dui sem, efficitur quis elit non, lacinia blue placerat risus. Sed mattis est purus. Pellentesque blandit eros ligula, yellow ac fermentum green magna interdum red maximus. Phasellus erat urna, dictum eu porta quis, ornare quis ligula.</p>
  <p>Maecenas consequat, leo in tempus blandit, massa ligula faucibus dolor, at feugiat odio elit sed elit. Quisque molestie nulla in orci facilisis, et auctor mauris elementum. Sed mi neque, efficitur ut aliquet a, luctus lobortis lectus. Nunc pretium cursus
    nisi, at aliquet erat viverra sed. Phasellus red erat ligula, maximus quis tincidunt eget, porttitor at dui. Mauris ut urna pharetra, mollis lacus at, posuere nisl. Aliquam a dapibus mi. Pellentesque vestibulum porta erat at maximus. Duis posuere
    tincidunt purus, vitae volutpat lectus varius vitae. Nam rutrum blue venenatis augue vel commodo. Suspendisse nec nulla eros.</p>
  <p>Duis lorem est bluetoth, blandit eget leo pharetra, rutrum semper ante. Suspendisse vestibulum in risus id hendrerit. Nulla volutpat velit ac tortor lacinia euismod. In non purus dictum, pellentesque mauris ac, viverra est. Phasellus urna odio, sodales
    et nisl sed, condimentum volutpat ex. Duis et vulputate urna. Praesent sollicitudin lacinia felis, nec facilisis purus venenatis in. Integer yellow et lacus green dapibus eros vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque ultricies, nunc yellow dictum yellow luctus blue posuere, orci ex dapibus tortor, vel ultrices nulla velit quis neque. Mauris nisl ligula, lobortis id metus quis, gravida eleifend diam. Curabitur sapien nibh, faucibus sed diam et, luctus
    imperdiet risus. Cras urna nunc, luctus sit amet red libero ac, tristique egestas nibh. Cras dui elit, malesuada sit amet quam eget, efficitur maximus magna. Nulla auctor dignissim dictum. Curabitur condimentum semper lacus, tristique bibendum justo
    lobortis et. Interdum green et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus finibus diam at auctor condimentum. Morbi at nisi nec purus red maximus pulvinar. Duis at lorem ultricies, blandit velit sed, condimentum justo. Suspendisse
    potenti.</p>
  <p>Redux, Morbi accumsan tortor eros, vel consectetur lectus iaculis red vitae. Integer rhoncus imperdiet purus, in mattis justo tempor at. Sed tristique porta ligula, eu gravida erat red congue ac. Donec leo justo, fermentum nec nisi auctor, vulputate
    fringilla ex. Morbi ut tempor tortor, quis tincidunt velit. Integer in commodo lorem. Sed vestibulum vestibulum mi at semper. Suspendisse nisi tellus, vestibulum porttitor purus nec, pharetra semper erat. Sed lorem blue turpis, euismod sit amet hendrerit
    non, red, yellow. consequat ac tellus. Fusce nec iaculis elit. Cras non molestie est. Aenean faucibus neque metus, nec tempus est consequat et. Quisque accumsan, turpis vel vulputate dignissim, dui erat scelerisque enim, sit amet auctor nisl green
    arcu non odio. Quisque eleifend id dolor a egestas.</p>
```

Создал класс `ChangeColors`, у него есть два метода, `addElement`, в его первый аргумент записывается элемент, который позже будет использоваться при изменении HTML'а. Также есть метод `init`, в его первый аргумент передаются цвета, с которыми вы будете работать (Пример: `['purple', 'pink', 'gray']` и другие подобные массивы с разным кол-вом элементов), сам метод берёт список `els` в котором занесены элементы. Вот примера кода где есть работа с ним:

```js
new ChangeColor(document.querySelector('p')) // Или querySelectorAll, для класса нет разницы.
  .init(['red', 'purple', 'grey', 'brown'])
```